# Android Studio не открывает проект

Tags: android, android-studio

Здравствуйте во время открытие проекта из исходников 
появляется это сообщения

---

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

---

Comment: Попробуйте увеличить максимальный размер кучи с помощью ключа `-XX:MaxHeapSize=value`.

Comment: можно подробнее 
я только начинаю осваивать студию

Comment: Закройте Android Studio. Перейдите в каталог `Android\Android Studio\bin`, там будет файл `studio.exe.vmoptions` (таких файла два – для различных разрядностей, используйте нужный). В этом файле увеличьте параметр `-Xmx`.

Comment: сделал, ошибка осталась(
1400 - потолок если выше студия вовсе не запускается

Comment: может есть какие нибудь еще выходы из этого положения?

Comment: Попробуйте еще вот [так](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045417/android-studio-gradle-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap/31760855#31760855).